# Ionic 4 wordpress authentication

Tags: angular, wordpress, ionic4

Good day Expert. Please I am new to ionic and angular and I have a little worry, Please help me out. I am using WordPress JWT plugins to authenticate users in my ionic 4 apps, but the issue am having is that when a user try to log in the first time it returns null, with this error message –

**https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/null?consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxx.
–HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: “OK”, URL: “https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/cu…ecret=cs_xxxxxxxxxxx”, ok: false, …}**,

but the local storage returns the customer data and id with a toast showing login successfully. But the user tries it the second time, that’s when the user will be authenticated, so it only when the user tries it twice before it authenticated. But I want a user to be authenticated once the login is successful

I don’t know what I have done wrong. This is my code. Thank You

**login.page.ts**

```
loginForm(){

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      if((this.password != '') &&  (this.CFS.validateEmail(this.email))) {

        console.log('Email: ',this.email);

        console.log('Password: ',this.password);

        this.auth.loginCustomer(this.email,this.password).then((response) => {

      if(response['token']){

        console.log('Returned Token: ',response['token']);

        console.log('Returned user enamil: ',response['user_email']);

        this.CFS.presentToast('Login successful', 'buttom',2000, 'success');

        this.auth.getUserData(this.email).subscribe((userData) => {

         this.customerData = userData;

          console.log('Customer Data: ', this.customerData);

         let currentUserId = this.customerData[0].id;

         localStorage.setItem('currentUserId', currentUserId);

         let found = localStorage.getItem('currentUserId');

         console.log('local storage id', found);

        });
          this.route.navigateByUrl('/home');
      } else {

        this.CFS.presentToast('Invalid username or password', 'buttom',2000,'danger');
      } 

    });

      } else {

        this.CFS.presentToast('Please fill  the form correctly', 'buttom',2000,'danger')

      }

    });

  }
```

**Home.page.ts**

```
   customerId:any;

   customerData: any = {

    avatar_url: 'not found',

  }

  constructor(private CFS: CommonfunctionService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private auth: AuthService, private WC: WoocommerceService, private modalPop: ModalController) {

   }
     ngOnInit() {  
    let isUserLoggedIn =  localStorage.getItem('currentUserId');

    this.WC.getUserInfo(isUserLoggedIn).subscribe((data)=>{

      this.customerData = data;

      console.log('user data', this.customerData);

    }); 

    this.WC.getWalletBalance(isUserLoggedIn).subscribe((data) =>{

      this.mybalance = data;

      console.log('All Orders balance by a customer', this.mybalance);

    });
  }
```

Comment: In the first time you login, if you said that alert shows login successfull then its entering the if(response['token']){.... so that mean its returning the token . But does returned token return a token?

Comment: Thanks for your response. this is the message I get  when I try to login ---Customer Data: email: "name@gmail.com"first_name: ""last_name: ""role: "customer"username: "name"
login.page.ts: local storage id 77..... https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/null?consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxxxxconsumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxxx. Yes it returns a token.

Comment: Set local storage.setitem at the begining of if (reponse token found) { add it here at beging ..} since in your code at the same time the request to store also is the request of get so at same time the get will not take any value but for next times, it can get the item from storage since its already set...

Comment: Please can you help edit my code with what you  suggest I should, I try to set  local storage.setitem at the begining of if (reponse token found) but still having same issue. thanks

Comment: You need to provide everything related to the question including auth.getUserData function at least since your variables are unclear and don't know what you mean with each one..

Comment: Ok I will, Thanks